# Doubt about kswapd reclaimation?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, memory

In `kswapd` page reclamation flow what is difference between `shrink_zone()` and `shrink_slab()`, which pages are included in zone `lruvec` and `shrinker_list`. I want to know which pages are added in `lurvec` and `shrinker_list`.